# Php function to decode UTF-16 Unicode to emoji

Tags: php, unicode

I have tried many code snippets here at stackoverflow without success.

I am looking for a php function to convert -

```
"This is a smiley "%uD83D%uDE0B" 

to  

"This is a smiley "
```

Here is a working example of what I am trying to achieve.

http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Under: Decode/Unescape Unicode Entities

Comment: What format is `%u....` supposed to be? That's not one of the standard character escaping formats I recognise.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60b/index.htm I cant find the format you're talking about.

Comment: yes it is, I need a function to convert %uD83D%uDE0B > D83DDE0B > 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may be one way to work around your `%u` syntax

```
$emoji = '%uD83D%uDE0B';
print 'This is my emoji: '. json_decode('"' . str_replace('%', '\\', $emoji) . '"');
```

base on [Print Unicode characters PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539412/print-unicode-characters-php#26658360)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want, How can i have the output in variable ($str) instead of print ?

Comment: change `print '...';` to `$str = '...';` instead