# convert decimal value to unicode characters in php

Tags: php, unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

i need to convert decimals values into unicode and display the unicode character in PHP.

so for example, 602 will display as this character: **ɚ**

after [referencing this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539412/print-unicode-characters-php), i was able to piece this together:

```
echo  json_decode('"' . '\u0' . dechex(602) . '"' );
```

this seems pretty error-prone.  is there a better way to do this?

i was unable to get [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to work since it seemed to want to start with a string, not a decimal.

EDIT:  in order to do characters between 230 and 250, *double* prefixed zeros are required:

```
 echo   json_decode('"' . '\u00' . dechex(240) . '"' );  // ð
 echo   json_decode('"' . '\u00' . dechex(248) . '"' );  // ø
 echo   json_decode('"' . '\u00' . dechex(230) . '"' );  // æ
```

in some cases, no zero is required:

```
echo json_decode('"' . '\u' . dechex(8592) . '"' );  // ←
```

this seems strange.

Comment: Are you sure json_decode is the correct function to use? I don't know much about Unicode but json is a text representation of an object/array. I don't quite see how that relates to "emojis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `eval` is generally to be avoided, it seems strictly-controlled enough to be fine here.

```
echo eval(sprintf('return "\u{%x}";',$val));
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `sprintf` part isn't *strictly* needed. However, using `sprintf` *ensures* that what is passed is in fact a hex code and *nothing else*, thus making the `eval` safe.

Comment: Ha!  i knew somebody would blow away my answer!    but thank you for not downvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo json_decode(sprintf('"\u%04x"',$val));
```

this ultimately worked for me, but i would not have found this without the answer from ***Niet the Dark Absol***

Comment: This won't work correctly for codepoints larger than 65535 (\xFFFF) - of which unicode has many. The JSON `\u` escape syntax is limited to 16 bits - the JSON spec requires larger values be encoded as a UTF-16 surrogate pair.

Answer (score 0):

normally, when i attempt to answer my own question, some SO wizard comes along and shows me a built-in function that i should have known about.  but until that happens, this is all i can think of:

```
 $leading_zeros = null;

 if  ( strlen(strval(dechex($val))) >= 4 )       {
     $leading_zeros = '';
 } else if  ( ctype_alpha(dechex($val)[0]) )     {
     $leading_zeros = '00';
 } else if  ( ctype_digit(dechex($val)[0]) )     {
     $leading_zeros = '0';
 }
 echo json_decode('"' . '\u' . $leading_zeros . dechex($val) . '"' );
```

EDIT:  when trying to something similar for javaScript, the documentation tells me the format is supposed to look like  "\u####'  four digits.   i dont know if this is similar to PHP or not.

Comment: Probably don't look at jScript. This an early javascript-based language my microsoft Pretty dated at this point

Comment: apologies, Evert, i did not know there even was an actual "jScript", i just use it for shorthand when referencing javascript.  i have since changed it while selecting the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `IntlChar` available I'd recommend using [`IntlChar::chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.chr.php):

```
var_dump(IntlChar::chr(602));
```

Failing that, something like the following avoids any eval/json_decode trickery:

```
var_dump(iconv('UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8', pack('N', 602)));
```