# Browser does not display umlaut correctly when concatenating

Tags: php

My browser (chrome and firefox) does not display the umlaut "ö" correctly, once I concatenate a string with the umlaut character.

[image: BILD]

```
// words inside string with umlaute, later add http://www.lageplan23.de instead of "zahnstocher" as the correct solution
$string = "apfelsaft siebenundvierzig zahnstocher gelb ethereum österreich";

// get length of string
$l = mb_strlen($string);

$f = '';
// loop through length and output each letter by itself
for ($i = 0; $i <= $l; $i++){
    // umlaute buggy when there is a concatenation
    $f .= $string[$i] . " ";
}

var_dump($f);
```

When I replace `$string[$i] . " ";` with `$string[$i];` everything works as expected.

[image: BILD]

Why is that and how can I fix it so I can concatenate each letter with another string?

Comment: It seems when multi-byte characters are placed next to each other, it can be interpreted as a multi-byte character. Like if character with ASCII values 195 and 182 are placed together, the hex becomes C3B6 which is hex representation for that character (https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=00F6&mode=hex). So, when they are separated by space, it becomes some other characters.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993420/4688321

Comment: Questions like this always send me back to this article on how the string type is "broken" -- it's a good reminder of how the bytes are stored and how the interpretation of multi-byte characters can sometimes be flawed. https://mortoray.com/2013/11/27/the-string-type-is-broken/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, a string is a series of bytes. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details) clumsily refers to those bytes as characters at times.

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support.

And then later

> It has no information about how those bytes translate to characters, leaving that task to the programmer.

Using `mb_strlen` over just `strlen` is the correct way to get the number of actual characters in a string (assuming a sane byte order and internal encoding to begin with) however using array notation, `$string[$i]` is wrong because it only accesses the bytes, not the characters.

The proper way to do what you want is to split the string into characters using `mb_str_split`:

```php
// words inside string with umlaute, later add http://zahnstocher47.de instead of "zahnstocher" as the correct solution
$string = "apfelsaft siebenundvierzig zahnstocher gelb ethereum österreich";

// get length of string
$l = mb_strlen($string);
$chars = mb_str_split($string);

$f = '';
// loop through length and output each letter by itself
for ($i = 0; $i <= $l; $i++){
    // umlaute buggy when there is a concatenation
    $f .= $chars[$i] . " ";
}

var_dump($f);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/JIQoE